# Transfer Function, what does s Stand for

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory

Trying to understand what the variable s is for transfer functions (if there is a common accepted use of it). In the problem space I am working in, control theory, I believe I have seen definitions of "short period poles", "complex Laplace transform variable", and at
http://web.mit.edu/2.14/www/Handouts/PoleZero.pdf it describes s as s = sigma + j * omega (I guess as a complex variable). Any insight into one of these being correct or if I am missing a better common use, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out the Wikipedia [Transfer Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_function#Linear_time-invariant_systems) page. I don't know what a "short period pole" is, but the other two definitions seem correct to me (even if not providing much insight).

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the second opinion, you'd be surprised how hard it is to google any variation of "transfer function s" since every webpage has an s in it :)

Comment: No doubt that $s$ is a complex variable in Laplace transform. Decomposing it into $\sigma+j\omega$ way is dangerous because it tends to say (what you find in old books) that setting $\sigma=0$ you can reach the Fourier Transform. The best way to consider the $s$ in a Laplace Transform is as a purely formal parameter.

Comment: Thank you Jean! Great answer :D